# Verification Token changes as I navigate a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am building a web scraping tool that will log into a website navigate to a dropdown menu and request the information in one of the options but when I was navigating the site I realized that the verification token changes as I go. Is this why this code only presents an error at the requests.post?
I'm very confused at this point and unfortunately, the website is subscription-based so you won't be able to see it for yourself.
https://www.ask-socrates.com/Watchlist

Form data at login (not including password and email)

__RequestVerificationToken: -zF8yJdcBbrtsgf1rt5BhMaZTsFFG9Ee4dvvbcg3okqdujREVFDqsWBTeMl8FQ5qopUgxcxYMeid2tOs8TGRb17FPeskb9vyN3a0hyiTr4m6JCNWY4x6RmfBTbAiXsESksJPbbf0O565KeROYAptDw2

Form data after clicking a dropdown option(the marketId just identifies the dropdown option)

marketId: 5653923ac7eb6e355878bfe6

__RequestVerificationToken: 3vcFk9PpXO611piNg6N_9btNuacA3q_4Eo8_EjwL6tAYC6B5CbmQYQVvL8olqbleb_Dkrxc6OR2Xxf8Tt_wrQZ5HmijI2iKnkUU-TApbb9uFeSgOsc06BWxmDNVblKNJyB0hTk2du7CdEAknZ9LisA2

here is my code
not sure if anyone will be able to help with the given info
Thanks anyways

```
def create_session(email,password,base_url, login_url,):
s = requests.session()
print('session')

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36", 'authority': base_url, 'origin': None, 'path': login_url}

token = s.get(base_url).cookies['__RequestVerificationToken']
print(token)
login_data = {
    'EmailAddress': email,
    'Password': password,
    '__RequestVerificationToken':token
}

login_req = s.post(base_url + login_url, headers = HEADERS, data=login_data)
print('login: code('+str(login_req.status_code) + ')')
print(s.cookies)
print('cookies\n')

cookies = {
    '__Host-Socrates-SessionId': s.cookies['__Host-Socrates-SessionId'],
    '__RequestVerificationToken': s.cookies['__RequestVerificationToken'],
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.385809897.1653610509',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.983879844.1653610509',
    'Socrates-UserSettings': s.cookies['Socrates-UserSettings'],
    'Socrates-Login': s.cookies['Socrates-Login'],
}

headers = {
        'authority': 'www.ask-socrates.com',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
        # 'cookie': '__Host-Socrates-SessionId=vmykm2llyvcnjb141ogunwqa; __RequestVerificationToken=VE6qerHW2rCA4goyK0b6HhxQ80XqTyIc9wi7Ob22if9JVxTOPHNx1T9OoxrOLKjKufvuiZ3hvHdN_83WuIL1Ct5md709dhewDiqXkS-AScQ1; _ga=GA1.2.385809897.1653610509; _gid=GA1.2.983879844.1653610509; Socrates-UserSettings=%7b%22SocratesSpeech%22%3a0%2c%22MenuPinned%22%3afalse%2c%22GMWViewer%22%3a%22grid%22%2c%22TourGuideEnabled%22%3atrue%2c%22ShowHelpMessages%22%3afalse%2c%22ChartTheme%22%3a2%2c%22FontSize%22%3a%221.4em%22%7d; Socrates-Login=_NZZoN5xNL7qHYBH9WZcit_OpTBVeFwBsNciG5ehBe5UxHekYPrT3d_i45Pm90upHgj3mERjw8zL-Q65R9yyIpJ-xRVKLuTQSaf30jvJnk2gUsKfWHoLkM372tJv9tkD8QO8G641o0qeG4ttyBTq8IBZB5GePxY4MLQ4UCN7dPn9UPqjqgfLfwPZc50IeFYb4Ich4T_vOP7ALnKmorl9T4aotGiyD1kvWCBCsfT9m-gp0EXPbxF397NcZGgty8Ub1wzpE1DPVUx0-O4zZCf4yu55t4d2QeYZ4vg3FLpg3CIWcpLtODF_tILNLNx4yqPJN7Xabe3MtYev7x62_vHrwApf9Ati1cs1jEB4VKBtSQWvTqm1N-7xFlYA6h9SSdQY; _gat=1',
        'origin': 'https://www.ask-socrates.com',
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }
data = {
    'marketId': '5653923ac7eb6e355878bfe6', 
    '__RequestVerificationToken': s.cookies['__RequestVerificationToken']    }

response = requests.post('https://www.ask-socrates.com/Watchlist/GetUserWatchListView', cookies=s.cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)


return s,token
```

Comment: Some sites renew your token with every response, or at least with every new full page load. So, if you're going through various steps in the process of trying to scrape data, you will need to get the new token every time you get such a response, and use the updated token in the next request.

Comment: @Grismar I thought I would try renewing it but when I run the same get token code I get this error "name='__RequestVerificationToken', domain=None, path=None"

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message, or at least not a complete one?

Comment: raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='__RequestVerificationToken', domain=None, path=None"

Comment: Please post the full trace for the error as part of the question, as well as the explanation that you tried this - it will help to make clear what causes the problem, and probably point others at a solution for you.

Comment: After running this line for the second time(it works the first time): token = s.get(base_url).cookies['__RequestVerificationToken']         I hope to get a new and updated verification token because the token seems to refresh after every request.

Comment: I then get this error, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 50, in <module>
    s,token = create_session(email,password,base_url, login_url)
  File "", line 50, in create_session
    token = s.get(str(base_url)+'Watchlist').cookies['__RequestVerificationToken']
  File "", line 328, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "", line 399, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='__RequestVerificationToken', domain=None, path=None"

Comment: As before: "Please post the full trace for the error as part of the question, as well as the explanation that you tried this - it will help to make clear what causes the problem, and probably point others at a solution for you." - don't put stuff like this in the comments, the question becomes a useless mess that way, you can just edit the question to improve it.

Comment: always put error in question, not in comments. It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.